# Why is my python script dying in the background when called from PHP?

Tags: python, php

I want to have a PHP program call a python program and have it run the background.  When I call this from the shell `nohup python3 automation.py args >/dev/null 2>&1 &` , everything runs fine.  I run `top` and `jobs` and I can see that it is executing.  The script finishes successfully.

Now I would like this script to be called from a PHP program and then run in the background, so I am using this command, which is the same above.  For the program not to hang, I output it to null.
`exec('nohup python3 automation.py args >/dev/null 2>&1 &')`

Everything runs fine for awhile when I administer a `top` but then it dies after a few seconds and I am left scratching my head to figure out why.  How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38179655/6472849

Comment: @brice I tried that and it didn't work for me.  I have no problem calling the script from php and executing, however the python process dies prematurely.  When I call it from the command line with the same args however it runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  The linux user that PHP is used when commands are executed is `www-data`.  That user didn't have write permissions for the file.  To log in as www-data for testing, run this `su -s /bin/bash www-data`.  Any command you execute in the shell should be equivalent to calling it from PHP.